# How to add a 3D object model in my .NET Maui application without using Evergine or <model-viewer> and WebView integration

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm working on a .NET MAUI application that displays live details of cars. I need to integrate a 3D model into the app with interactive features such as rotation, zooming, and specific views like having the car door face the user on a button click.

The 3D model is currently in .glb format but I too have .obj, .gltf and .usdz format. I can switch to them if required.

Here's a brief overview of what I tried and what problems I am encountering:

**1. Evergine:** It is a graphics software to create 3D applications and designs just like unity and blender. Evergine can integrate the projects you make to a .NET Maui Solution.

[Image showing the 3D project window opened in Evergine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFhvA.png)

The Problem with Evergine is that when you open the project as a Maui Code in Visual Studio, It creates two different projects in the same solution - one for the scene and the 3D object, and the other one is the Maui app solution which imports the first solution as a 3D Canvas.

[Image showing file structure of the solution and two projects in the same solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrFPq.png)

This is how the 3D Canvas and and views are imported in the mobile app project:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyCar3D.MAUI.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:evergine="clr-namespace:MyCar3D.MAUI.Evergine">
    <Grid>
        <evergine:EvergineView x:Name="evergineView" />
        <!-- The above code is for using the canvas -->
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem is the app is already in development with other developers collaborating on it. Adding a new project in this one will create a lot of confusion and maybe after that we have to start everything from scratch (Correct me if I am wrong). Thus it is not feasible.

**2. <model-viewer> and WebView integration:** In this process I created a webpage using `<model-viewer>`tags and APIs and hosted it on GitHub pages and used `WebView` control in the Maui app.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Car 3D</title>
    <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.4.0/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    model-viewer{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <model-viewer alt="" src="assets\car-glb.glb" ar ios-src="assets\car-usdz.usdz" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls touch-action="pan-y"></model-viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image showing the file structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux7kF.png)

The problem is this process always require an internet connection.

I want a solution where I can import the 3D object file in the app without having to create a second project just like that in Evergine and also it should not require an internet connection.

Any guidance or code examples to achieve these interactive features would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately your question does not meet Stack Overflow Guidelines. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) check this out.

Comment: AFAIK there is no universal model format for 3d  objects, and you have not provided any detail about the format you are using

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've modified the question. Please check if its good or not? @AndyDonegan